# Code efficient?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My combinedata.csv file has 11230909 rows and file size is about 1.6GB. When I try to load this and construct vector string into C++ this takes more than 5 hours.

Is my code not optimal or time efficient. How to reduce the time to as much as posssible.  Any idea how much optimal code take to import file of 1.6GB and create variable.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>


using namespace std;
vector <string> data;

vector <string> readcsvfile()
{   
string line, val;   
ifstream file("combinedata.csv");

while (!file.eof())
{    
    getline(file, line);

    if (!file.good())
        break;
    stringstream newline(line);
    newline << line + ",\n";

    if (!newline.good())
        break;

    while (getline(newline, val, ','))
    {
        if (val != "NA")
            data.push_back(val);
        else
            break;
    }

}

return data;
}

void main()
{
vector <string> data;
data = readcsvfile();
cout << data.size();
cin.get();
}
```

Comment: When dealing with large files, it's important NOT to load everything in memory (i.e. RAM). Depending on the task, write iterators to read incrementally the file. CPU time is way cheaper than RAM.

Comment: A variable with 1.68GB is unlikely to be optimal. Why are you loading the entire thing in one go, or more correctly why do you need it all to be in memory at the same time.

Comment: When I import using C code it is way faster. It take only 10 second to import the full file. I am loading full file just to check how much time it takes. Even If I call block by block and apply some logic on the block and move to next block. I still have to pass through almost all the lines. This whole process in C takes 10 seconds. So much of time difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my code not optimal or time efficient.

It is not. `std::vector` and `std::string` allocate memory opportunistically, meaning you will get lots of reallocations (each one larger than the next) as you fill in your vector.

I assume this is the main difference between the C and C++ code you tried with: in C you didn't have fancy structures optimized for different use cases (i.e. different than reading a 1.6 Gb file).

> How to reduce the time to as much as posssible. Any idea how much optimal code take to import file of 1.6GB and create variable.

No idea on "how much optimal code" it would take :(

To reduce processing time, try different algorithms to read the data, and measure efficiency; Two things I would try:

- read file as binary and parse it manually;
- pass once and count strings/size, then pre-allocate result space, then pass second time and read the data.

Comment: which language is fast C or C++ for big data?

Comment: both (the difference is that C++ supports higher level abstractions, but this has little to do with efficiency).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I'll put it here for now as it won't go in a comment:

**This...**

```
while(!file.eof())
{    
    getline(file, line);

    if(!file.good())
        break;

    // ...
}
```

**...can be done more simply like this:**

```
while(getline(file, line))
{    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't optimal but I don't think that's your problem, I think it's more the size of your file that's the issue. If you wanted to do better code though you could:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    vector<string> data;

    copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(ifstream("combinedata.csv")),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            back_inserter(data),
            [](const string& i){return i != "NA";});
}
```

As is pointed out by [utnapistim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186997/utnapistim) this won't work in gcc prior to gcc 5.0, because there is a [bug with moving streams](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316). That doesn't seem to be you cause you're using `void main` which is only supported by Visual Studio. But for anyone who *is* working on gcc older than 5.0 you can accomplish this by replacing the body of `main` with:

```
vector<string> data;
ifstream file("combinedata.csv");

copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(file),
        istream_iterator<string>(),
        back_inserter(data),
        [](const string& i){return i != "NA";});
```

Comment: @user1177819 If you declared `i` as a `string` that's not an error. I didn't use the variable `line` in my solution, so it's likely a copy paste error. Anyway I updated my solution. I decided I could do it without another function.

Comment: You cannot do this: `istream_iterator<string>(ifstream("combinedata.csv"))` - because the ifstream is a const reference in this case and the istream_iterator doesn't bind to a _const_ reference. You need to declare the stream on a separate line.

Comment: still error.   Error 6 error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source? e:\param_cpp\hft\hft\hft.cpp 98 1 hft
 7 IntelliSense: expected a ';' e:\Param_CPP\hft\hft\hft.cpp 25 13 hft

Comment: @utnapistim That's a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316) in gcc. That doesn't allow moving of streams that's fixed in gcc5.0

Comment: @user1177819 What are you compiling on? Do you have C++11?